# How to create GUI from SQL Edge instance on mac m1 in docker

Tags: docker, macos, azure-sql-edge

[image: docker start sqledge]

Managed to get Docker instance of SQL Edge running on Macbook M1 but to see GUI so I can connect to database. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a SQL Edge server from a Mac client you can use Azure Data Studio which [supports macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver16#macos-installation). At this time, there is no native Apple silicon version of Azure Data Studio but it is an electron app and works with Rosetta.